# My program is storing my array backwards

Tags: arrays, processing, record

I'm using a program called "Processing" to write this code. The code is supposed to record mouse coordinates in an array when u drag your mouse, and then when you release your mouse, it will show a circle following the path of the coordinates stored in the array, but right now it plays the circle from when I stopped dragging my mouse, to where i started dragging. This is supposed to be the other way around, but I've tried a lot of get it the reverse, but nothing I do seems to work :/

If you could show me it would be really helpful! I'm sure I missed something really obvious.

```
int num = 100;
int[] x = new int[num];
int[] y = new int[num];
boolean released = false;
int arrayIndex;
boolean drag = false;

void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
  noStroke();
  smooth();
  fill(255, 102);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  if (released==true){
      arrayIndex= (arrayIndex+1)%100;
      ellipse(x[arrayIndex],y[arrayIndex],20,20);  

  }

}


void mouseDragged(){
  drag=true;
  x[0] = mouseX;
  y[0] = mouseY;
  for (int i = num - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    x[i] = x[i-1];
    y[i] = y[i-1];
  }



}

void mouseReleased(){
 released=true;
}
```

Comment: It would help if you tagged this with the language you're using. It looks to me like you're adding values to your array starting at the top and working down, while the code that reads the array to draw the path starts at the bottom and works up.

Comment: @MikeW `Processing` is the name of the language, it's a java framework.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed you add coordinates from end to begin and read form begin to end. So reverse the display iteration, eithr by using `frameCount`, or a intermediary var...

using frameCount:

```
int num = 100;
int[] x = new int[num];
int[] y = new int[num];
boolean released = false;
int arrayIndex;
boolean drag = false;

void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
  noStroke();
  smooth();
  fill(255, 102);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  if (released==true){
      arrayIndex= (num-1) - (frameCount+1)%100;
      ellipse(x[arrayIndex],y[arrayIndex],20,20);  

  }

}


void mouseDragged(){
  drag=true;
  x[0] = mouseX;
  y[0] = mouseY;
  for (int i = num - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    x[i] = x[i-1];
    y[i] = y[i-1];
  }



}

void mouseReleased(){
 released=true;
}
```

using another var:

```
int num = 100;
int[] x = new int[num];
int[] y = new int[num];
boolean released = false;
int arrayIndex;
boolean drag = false;

void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
  noStroke();
  smooth();
  fill(255, 102);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  if (released==true){
      arrayIndex= (arrayIndex+1)%100;
      int reversed = (num-1) - arrayIndex; 
      ellipse(x[reversed],y[reversed],20,20);  

  }

}


void mouseDragged(){
  drag=true;
  x[0] = mouseX;
  y[0] = mouseY;
  for (int i = num - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    x[i] = x[i-1];
    y[i] = y[i-1];
  }



}

void mouseReleased(){
 released=true;
}
```